# How do I use dead eye to its full potential in Red Dead Redemption 2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Throughout the whole campaign of Red Dead 2, I never knew how to properly use 'dead eye' by this I mean, I would only use it for the shooting in slow motion. All I would like to know is how to use it properly, were you can pick how many shots go on each enemy instead of just one shot every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a tutorial in the campaign at the point where you unlock the ability to "paint" targets.  I can't remember where that gets unlocked.

If memory serves, when the reticle is over the target, hit R1/RB to mark your shot. When you've finished marking all your targets, hit R2/RT to let off all the shots. Keep in mind that time is still passing, just slowly. If a target gets into cover while you're marking targets, you could miss your shot when you start firing.

Comment: One [source](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/rdr2-how-to-target-multiple-enemies-with-dead-eye/) to confirm the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the answer, this will help a lot when I'm playing online, because dead eye is not in slow motion in online.